For citations, Should I use the citation of the mentioned name or the journal it was in?
An article I want to cite mentiones an author and has paraphrased a sentence. I would like to refer to that sentence but I'm not sure who to reference in the in-text citation: the author of the journal or the person they paraphrased? An example of the situation is, "As Jason (2005) states, ...".

The citation is of the paper and its author(s). The person mentioned/quoted should be named in the text, but the citation is of the source you have read.
So, Jason states (Smith et al, 2005) ...
This makes the second hand reporting clear. (I assume Jason is the person being quoted and Smith... authored the paper in which you find the quote.

The important question here is what you are trying to cite, and to what end. For clarity, you are talking about paper A which cites paper B.
If the important point that you want is in paper B, then find, read, and cite paper B.
If the important point is author A's comment on paper B, then cite paper A.
If it's about B, but you feel that A also added something, you can cite both.
If the important point is in B but you genuinely can't get hold of B, after some trying, then you could do something like "B, quoted in A, said that..." but it's not ideal.

And it's a good idea for the "some trying" to incorporate methods described in How can I find an old, obscure, or otherwise inaccessible paper when the usual methods fail?

If all Jason did was paraphrase, then it is better to use the original article that was paraphrased - let's say it is by Smith.
Find Smith, read it, and cite it. Then there is no reason to cite Jason.
